# Compression or encryption?

Tags: encryption, compression

I got a file that seems to not have anything readable into it (for a human)

How can I be sure that it hasn't anything readable for a human? Because it's way too large to read it entirely (maybe a program that searches for words or entropy or I don't know.)

How can I know if this file is compressed or encrypted, or both? And is it possible that it has a proprietary compression so I can't distinguish it from encryption?

Because if I can make sure that it's encrypted, I can stop my work directly, but if it's just encoded/compressed, maybe I can find a way to read it

(I tried to compress it with the basic Windows archiver and it loses 18% of its size. Does it mean that it's not encrypted? Does an encryption permit that much compression?)

Comment: In general there is no foolproof test to know if a file containing unknown data is encrypted or compressed. However, attempting to compress the data is one fairly good test to apply. If it compresses at all then that is evidence, but not proof, that it is neither compressed nor encrypted. Unfortunately, even some compressed and/or encrypted files will be compressible. In fact, encrypting a file with AES in ECB mode may still yield a compressible ciphertext if the plaintext file contains lots of repeated blocks. The old Linux penguin example illustrates this.

Comment: That's exactly my guess about this file (that is only partly compressed/encrypted), because when I read it manually I see a lot of zeroes part, so my guess is that it's that part who is compressed with my own compression. But like you say, this method does not gives me any informations about the not zero part... So no more informations

Comment: Is there somewhere any software who tries all known uncompression methods and check if it lessen the entropy or not? And if a particular method lessen it, it asks the user to check if any part becomes readable. If no methods lessen the entropy, then it either encrypted either compressed with a proprietary method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible to create a compression format for which all possible sequences of bits is valid. In that case, you would not be able to distinguish the compressed data from random or encrypted data.

I am not aware of a commonly implemented compressed format that has that property. You could try all of the decompressors you can find on the data to see if any continue to decompress through all of the data without erroring out. You can also try starting at different locations in your data, since there may be some sort of header before the compressed data.

Comment: So if the entire file is not compressed in the same way, it will output an error? In that case I should, like you say, uncompress until it stops and check if wether the file is bigger or if some parts becomes readable

Comment: Eventually. As an example, inflate will give an error on random data in just a few bytes most of the time, but sometimes it can take a few thousand bytes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Online Decryption

If you would like to decrypt the file. You could simply copy and paste everything inside of https://online-toolz.com/tools/text-encryption-decryption.php

that feature can decrypt messages fast.

#### Encoder & Decoder

https://www.base64decode.org/

I found this website a while ago, this website is trusted and fast with great reviews.
This method can also help with your request.

Comment: How online-toolz can decrypt anything without having the key and the algorithm?

How can I know if my file is base64 encoded or encoded with anything else?

Comment: For base64 the file is too large to submit, and even after decoding, the question stills the same => How can I be sure that it hasn't anything readable for a human? Because it's way too large to read it entirely (maybe a program who search for words or entropy or idk)

Comment: For encryption I highly doubt that the specific algorithm+key of online-toolz can decrypt anything that doesn't come out from the same page...

Comment: Do you have real knowledge about compression and encryption or you try only to get reputation by replying to random questions?